# Why is $db PDO object passed as null in constructor parameter?

Tags: php, database, constructor, pdo, null

I'm wondering why in the PHP code below, the PDO objects $db is passed as NULL. i.e. `$db=NULL` in the constructor parameter.

```
class ColoredListsUsers
{
    /**
     * The database object
     * @var object
     */
    private $_db;

    /**
     * Checks for a database object and creates one if none is found
     * @param object $db
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($db=NULL) /* why is #db passed as null here ? */
    {
        if(is_object($db))
        {
            $this->_db = $db;
        }
        else
        {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME;
            $this->_db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        }
    }
}
```

Earlier $db was declared as a PDO object:

```
// Create a database object
    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME;
        $db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

Just doesn't seem to make sense to make $db a PDO object then pass it as null.... 
code is from http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/creating-an-app-from-scratch-part-5/

Comment: You're not creating any `ColoredListsUsers` instances in the provided code.

Comment: It isn't being passed as NULL - that is a default parameter value for the constructor function. It allows one to _omit_ the `$db` parameter, in which case it will be default NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public function __construct($db=NULL)` means `$db` [is an optional parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). And if it's not specified then the default `NULL` value will be used.

In this case - look several lines below, the `else` body - the default connection is created.

Comment: Oh, so $db is always passed into the function; just if it has a value, the PDO, it retains it and the if() executes since it evaluates as an object, but if $db is passed without a value then it takes on the value of NULL and the else() executes? Am I thinking about this right?

Comment: @Gnuey: "but if $db is passed without a value" --- this is incorrect. The correct would be: "but if nothing is passed". Like `new ColoredListsUsers();`

Comment: Ah, ok. That's another explanation I was considering. Makes sense. Thank you.